# How to automate clicking a "SEND" button on a corporate security pop-up using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, popup

I have the following code in an Excel VBA module:

```
With OutlookMail
    .To = "mickey.mouse@disney.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Ride Review"
    .Body = "Please make the Turbo Spinner an express-lane ride."
    .Attachments.Add Path
    .Send
    SendKeys "{Enter}"
end With 'OutlookMail
```

The code works fine and will send an e-mail as expected. However, when the `.Send` command is executed, my company requires employees to fill out an e-mail security tool and then click an additional "SEND" / "CANCEL" button ("SEND" is highlighted by default). (NOTE: this is NOT a warning pop-up that has hundreds of post about it).

The problem becomes when this window pops-up I am unable to navigate away from pop-up (i.e. it retains focus and gives an audible 'ding' noise and flashes the pop-up when you try to click on another area of the desktop).

As such, I am not able to use the SendKeys function in VBA since Excel is no longer the active window and I am unable to continue to step through the code until I click "SEND" / "CANCEL" with my mouse. In fact, the `SendKeys "{Enter}"` command places a return in the module code after I click "SEND"/"CANCEL" and continue stepping through the code (as expected).

I have searched online to no avail for something similar. I am not sure there is a way to do this with Excel VBA given the fact that the code stops running until "SEND"/"CANCEL" is clicked, but perhaps there is a way to force it.

Comment: I would suggest to stay away from it since it's a company security requirement. It could lead you to trouble.

Comment: Yeah, why do you need to break the company enforcement rules? You'd better turn off the add-in which gives this warning.

Comment: Kostas and Astafiev I'm not trying to turn off or otherwise circumvent the "security" requirement. I just want to click the "SEND" button on the pop-up; the appropriate security containers are already checked. In other words, I'm not trying to do anything that will "get me in trouble" or is against company policy.

Comment: Would you provide information you found about warning messages that demonstrates this is different.

Comment: Sendkeys acts on the active window. If you step through code the active window is the module. You cannot step through Sendkeys to test Sendkeys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are dealing with a modal dialog window. When it is displayed to a user the code stops running and can be resumed only after it is closed. A possible solution is to develop an external utility (application) which can scan Outlook windows periodically and click buttons programmatically. [Microsoft Active Accessibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility) can help you with that. But it is not a trivial task.

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that. You will have to use Windows API to get the job done.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene!  That is what I figured.  Looks like we will just be clicking the send button on our own...